# Parse linear equation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

For example: if `2x + 1` is given as a string, how to use it in a function.

Say `x = 3` then we should get `2 * 3 + 1 = 7`.

Comment: I have not used it before but try http://mathjs.org/

Comment: Use google: http://algebra.js.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: use `eval()` .

***Note***: its only on '2x+1' static equation not for all.

```js
function calc() {
    var str = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var obj = document.getElementById('obj').value;
    str = str.replace('x', '*' + obj)
    console.log(str)
    console.log(eval(str))
 }

calc();
```

```html
Str:<input  id="input" value="2x+1"><br />
x:<input id="obj" type="number" value="3">
<button onclick="calc()">Evaluate</button>
```

Comment: Would not use eval() in this case, since it is a user input and anyone could input something like "alert('hi');1".

Comment: @Lain  is not in this case. see the OP question.Its just a example only one `2x+1` .not for all

Comment: Yes, that seems likely. OP probably only ever wants to parse static equations and not user inputs......

Comment: What if I wanted it to use input?

Comment: @PhoxKiD its already with input via input tag.

Comment: As @Lain mentioned, is there a way to restrict js commands using eval?

Comment: Well, in your case you could just check if the parameters are numeric. !isNaN(+(str)).

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

Without user input. I hope this will helps you.

```js
function linearEquation(x){
  var strEquation = "2x+1";
  var result = strEquation.replace('x', '*'+x);
  alert(eval(result));
}
linearEquation(3);
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="linearEquation(3)">Get Result</button>
```

Comment: How does this help at all? It's pretty much exactly what's posted in an answer earlier, without any explanation. Even worse, it's the same static solution.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli you can pass any value in parameter and then you will another result so it is depends on you.